# Covariance matrix of the measurement

Tags: bayesian, covariance, kalman-filter

I'm using a bayesian framework to estimate the pose of a moving vehicle with a single camera.
The state vector of the vehicle is $$ X = \begin{bmatrix}
 x\\
 y\\
 \theta\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates in the plan and $\theta$ is the heading angle. The state vector $X$ is constatntly updated in the prediction step.

In the correction step, an image retrieval algorithm compares the current image to a database of images by a measure based on pixel by pixel differences.
 Then, it returns the best match which is an image of index $j\in N$ together with its pose, the measurement $z$ $$ z= \begin{bmatrix}
 x_{m}\\
 y_{m}\\
 \theta_{m}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Let's say my current image is actually the image of index $j=1000$ but the algorithm returns $j=1005$, how to evaluate the uncertainty?
How to calculate the covariance matrix of this measurement?

Comment: There are so many unclear things in the question. What are $x,y,\theta$? What should we calculate the covariance of?

Comment: $x$, $y$ are the coordinates of the vehicle in the plan and $\theta$ is its heading. The movement is described by the state vector $X$ wchich is constantly updated in the prediction step. When it comes to the correction step using the image retrieval algorithm, this latter returns a $pose$ as well. How to evaluate the covariance matrix of this returned measurement.

Comment: Ok, then it is probably a bit easier to understand the question. Maybe you can edit in the comment to the question.

Comment: It is done. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. You can have a look at [Confusion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.